# I am having difficulty understanding how to solve the diophantine equation $18x + 28y = 10$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, linear-diophantine-equations

I think I might be misunderstanding how to solve diophantine equations. I seem to be making a mistake somewhere in my process, and I am having difficulty figuring out what it could be. Here is what I did:

$18x + 28y = 10$

gcd(18,28) = 2 and 2|10 so there are infinitely many solutions.

Reduce equation to $9x + 14y = 5$

let $x = -1$, $y = 1$

$9(-1) + 14(1) = 5$

$5 = 5$

And so we have one possible $x_0,y_0$

Plugging this into the following:

$x = x_0 + \frac{b}{d}n$ and $y = y_0 - \frac{a}{d}n$

we have all integral solutions are, $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$

$x = -1 + 14n$ and $y = 1 - 9n$

But the answer is supposed to be $x = -1 - 14n$, $y = 1 + 9n$. Am I possibly missing a step?

I was using the following theorem to solve this:

Let $ax + by = c$ be a linear Diophantine equation in the
two variables $x$ and $y$ and let d = gcd(a,b). If $d \nmid c$, then the equation has no solutions; if $d|c$, then the equation has infinitely many solutions. Furthermore, if $x_0$, $y_0$ is a particular solution of the equation, then all solutions are given by
$x$, $y$ where $x = x_0 + (\frac{b}{d})n$ and $y = y_0 - (\frac{a}{d})n$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Your $n$ is their $-n$. You're right but just have a slightly different notation from the answer.

Comment: Notice that, you work over $\mathbb Z$, not only $\mathbb Z^{+}$ or $\mathbb Z^{-}$.  Therefore, you can move $n\to-n$, since all values of $n$ cover all values of $-n$, when $n\in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: @lonestudent Can you explain the first part of your second sentence a little more? I understand all $n$ values includes $-n$ values as well, so why would I want to move it?

Comment: @notsimplelogic Both answers are correct and valid . You don't need any moving in that sense, I think .

Comment: (Avoid having your notation do double duty. That can be confusing if you're not certain of what you're doing) Your solution sets are the same. IE $ \{ (-1 + 14n , 1 - 9n) \}  = \{ (-1 - 14m, 1 + 9m ) \}$, under the bijection $n = -m$.  $\quad$ We could also write it as $ \{ (13 + 14a, -8 - 9a ) \}$, as evidenced by which bijection?

Comment: Find a particular solution, for example $(x,y)=(-1,1)$, and with it you have a standard way to find the general solution.

Comment: @CalvinLin Apologies about the late response. I don't have much knowledge about bijections besides a basic definition, so I don't feel confident. Could a = -a be the bijection?

Comment: @notsimplelogic No. The bijection is $n = a + 1$. For example, that gives us $ - 1 + 14n = -1 + 14 (a+1) = 13 + 14a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have obtained the solution set
$$
\begin{cases}
x = -1 + 14n \\
y = 1 - 9n.
\end{cases}
$$
Writing the solutions as ordered pairs $(x, y)$, the solutions are
$$
\ldots, \underset{n = -2}{\underbrace{(-29, 19)}}, \ \underset{n = -1}{\underbrace{(-15, 10)}}, \ \underset{n = 0}{\underbrace{(-1, 1)}}, \ \underset{n = 1}{\underbrace{(13, -8)}}, \ \underset{n = 2}{\underbrace{(27, -17)}}, \ldots.
$$

Now let's consider the solution set
$$
\begin{cases}
x = -1 - 14n \\
y = 1 + 9n.
\end{cases}
$$
According to this, the solutions would then be
$$
\ldots, \underset{n = -2}{\underbrace{(27, -17)}}, \ \underset{n = -1}{\underbrace{(13, -8)}}, \ \underset{n = 0}{\underbrace{(-1, 1)}}, \ \underset{n = 1}{\underbrace{(-15, 10)}}, \ \underset{n = 2}{\underbrace{(-29, 19)}}, \ldots.
$$
But this is the same as the list you obtained, just written in the opposite order!